# QR code data does not show up for SOME of my QR codes

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on my own little Python powered OMR multiple choice marking program. A big challenge for me!!

First step is to create qr codes for each student. This works OK, I generate 162 qr codes for 1 course.

I want to check them, make sure the data is in the code.

The data should be like this, a student number and a name:

> 2025010105:段赵元
> 2025010106:段卓含
>
> 2025010108:范玉虹

As you can see, for example, the data for student 2025010107 does not show in my loop. However, using my mobile phone to scan the qr code for 2025010107, I see the correct data. The data is there.

```
QRfiles = os.listdir(savepathQRcodes)
QRfiles.sort()

for f in QRfiles:
    img = cv2.imread(savepathQRcodes + f)
    detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
    data, bbox, straight_qrcode = detector.detectAndDecode(img)
    #text = data.split(':')
    #print('number, name: ', text[0], text[1])
    print(data)
```

**Do you have any idea why the data for some of the qr codes does not show up? The data is there, confirmed with my mobile phone.** (My guess is a computer memory problem)

From 162 qr codes, 20 or so do not show data in this loop. Most of the qr codes show the data in this loop.

However, if I open the folder with the qr codes, I can scan the codes which do not show data with my phone and I see the correct data. Same goes for all other qr codes I make.

I will need the data when I get around to marking, so I need to be sure that the qr codes can be read successfully in Python.

Also, it is not always the same qr codes which show no data. I have made them and read them many times for testing.

I have the latest version of opencv.

One thing I noticed was, when I reduced the qr code border size to border=1, I got less codes not showing data. I don't know if that is a clue to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try adding a loop?

```
for f in QRfiles:
    img = cv2.imread(savepathQRcodes + f)
    detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()
    data = None
    while not data:
        data, bbox, straight_qrcode = detector.detectAndDecode(img)
    #text = data.split(':')
    #print('number, name: ', text[0], text[1])
    print(data)
```

or maybe the data == '', so first identify what is in the blank data(perhaps None type or `' '`) then do the loop

that could be a possible fix, but unfortunately I do not know what causes this. if it happens to random qrcode, it might not be your fault.